# Stop Eclipse console from jumping to the bottom when printing results

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse when you run a program whose output is printed over time, every time a new line of output is printed the console automatically jumps to the bottom of the console (even when you scrolled up the results in the console). Is it possible to set the Eclipse console so that the output is printed "in the background" and does jump down and one can easily read the earlier results without interruptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just click on the small icon with the lock above the console view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a scroll lock button in the console menu (upper right) that will stop it from automatically scrolling.

The button with the lock is the scroll lock.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the so called [scroll lock](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-scrolllock_action.htm) in your [console view](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-console_view.htm).